# Ajax Layered Navigation load event to use in jquery

Tags: layered-navigation, ajax, jquery

I integrated [lazyload](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload/enabled.html) on an magento layered navigation page. 
First page load runs well, but when I use navigation no more images are shown.

This is propably due to the ajax call updating instead of reloading the page.

Here's my question:

**Is there any event on the end of the ajax load I can use triggering the lazyload function?**

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you check this explanation: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload/enabled_ajax.html

Basically you'll have to reset the lazyload once the AJAX layered navigation load has been done so lazyload is reset on the new images.

Depending on the system you're using for your AJAX layered navigation, you'll have to change the JavaScript in order to get it working.

Comment: Yes, I saw this already. But I don't know how to apply that to a standard magento theme. What's the right  id instead of `#container`? And what do I have to use instead of `images.html`

Comment: As I said, it depends on your AJAX layered navigation module, not really on the theme.